# how to reply on send Email which I send by using journey builder in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

how to reply on send Email which I send by using journey builder in marketing cloud.(In this way we verify that email is received or not )

Answer (score 0):

Your best way of verifying if an email is sent or not is view tracking information.

This can be accessed via :

1. Email Studio > Tracking > Journey Builder Sends
2. Query Activity on the _Sent, _Open data views
3. Tracking Extract

To handle replies, your best bet is to have Reply Mail Management configured in your account. For more information on this please visit : [Reply Mail Management](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/enterprise_reply_mail_management/)

Comment: Hi Data_Kid,
How to use Reply Mail Management in Marketing cloud and how can I see the customers reply in Marketing cloud.